# Run parallel function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I tried to test with my really simple code as below, but the error is "Too many output arguments."

```
function func1(x,y)
plot(x, y), xlabel('x'), ylabel('Sin(x)'), title('Sin(x) Graph'),
grid on, axis equal
end

function func2(x,y)
plot(x, y), xlabel('x'), ylabel('Cos(x)'), title('Cos(x) Graph'),
grid on, axis equal
end
```

the main is

```
x = 0:0.01:10;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);
funcs = {@func1, @func2} ;   % let fun1, fun2 be two functions 
arguments = {x y1;x y2} ;   % write the inputs of each function 
solutions = cell(1,2);                 % initialize the solution 
% use of parfor 
parfor ii = 1:2
      solutions{ii}=funcs{ii}(arguments{ii,:});
end
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Your functions don't have output arguments, but your function call does have an output argument. (`solutions{ii}`).

Comment: You cannot plot in a `parfor` loop AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, @David  You are right, I should create output variable or delete solutions{}.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, If I want to plot or run animations at the same time, how can I do that? if you have the experience, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you call the function

```
solutions{ii}=funcs{ii}(arguments{ii,:});
```

Expects an output, which you're assigning to `solutions{ii}`.

This wouldn't work within a normal loop, or even without a loop, the fact that you're trying to write a `parfor` is immaterial here...

Your functions are defined as

```
function func1(x,y)
% ...
function func2(x,y)
% ...
```

Neither of these have output arguments, so it's unclear what you expect to be assigning to `solutions{ii}` - this exactly matches the error message you're seeing "too many output arguments".

If you expect an output from your function, then declare one

```
function z = func1(x,y)
    z = x + y;
    % other stuff
end
```

Otherwise, don't request an output within the loop

```
parfor ii = 1:2        
    funcs{ii}(arguments{ii,:});
end
```